# i have a problem solving a system with gauss method (elimination).

Tags: gaussian-elimination

My teacher said I have to solve it with gauss method, I tried to make for example $0y$ but I can't come to the result. If someone can help me I would appreciate that.
$$2x+z=7$$
$$x+y=2$$
$$y-z=-2$$

I did like this: $$2x+0y+z=7$$
                  $$x+y+0z=2$$
                $$  0x+y-z=-2$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve your system of 3 equations and 3 unknowns for you.  You have
$$eq 1)  2x + 0y + z = 7$$
$$eq 2)   x + y  + 0z = 2$$
$$eq 3)   0z + y - z  = -2$$
Now adding equations 1) and 3) I get
$$ 2x + y = 5$$
Then subtracting equation 2) I find
$$ x = 3 $$
Now solving equation 2) I see the result
$$ y = -1$$
And finally using equation 1) again
$$ 2*(3) + z = 7$$
and z = 1

So the answer is (x,y,z) = (3,-1, 1)

A good tutorial on the gauss method of elimination can be found at

http://www.purplemath.com/modules/systlin6.htm

This set of equations is in gaussian form when it is triangular.  See link.

Here is another way of solving it, that uses gauss method of elimination.  Consider eq1) - 2* eq2)
$$0 -2y + z = 3$$
now add 2*eq3)
$$0 + 0 - z = -1$$
So now we have a nice triangular set of equations that we can back substitute.
This is half way done with a gauss method.
$$x+y+0=2$$
$$0+y-z=-2$$
$$0+0+z=1$$
Now substituting z=1 in for the middle equation, we find that y=-1.

Using this fact and the top equation, we find that x = 3.  Thus we have used the gauss method and the three answers are x=3, y=-1 and z=1.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: Does it mean we are using the gauss method (elimination)

Comment: If I had used the gauss method of elimination, I probrably would have found z first.

Answer (score 0):

second equation minus the third we obtain
$x+z=4$ (1')
(1)-(1'):
we get $x=3$

This is a first step in finding x, y, and z.